# Python recursive helper method returns none instead of int

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, quicksort

I wanted to write code such that I could find the k-th largest number using quick-sort and wrote the following in LeetCode, which LeetCode will call upon findKthLargest first

```
class Solution(object):
    def partition(self, arr,left,right):
        piv = arr[right]
        i = left-1
        counter = left
        while (counter<right):
            if (arr[counter]<piv):
               i = i+1
               tmp = arr[counter] 
               arr[counter]=arr[i]
               arr[i]=tmp
            counter = counter+1
        temp = arr[i+1]
        arr[i+1]=arr[right]
        print('pivot '+str(piv)+' at '+str(i+1))
        arr[right]=temp
        print("at the nmoment "+str(arr))
        return (i+1)
    def helper(self,arr,left,right,k):
        if (left>=right):
            return 
        p = self.partition(arr,left,right)
        print("p is now "+str(p))
        if (p==len(arr)-k):
  
            return int(arr[p])
        self.helper(arr,left,p-1,k)
        self.helper(arr,p+1,right,k)
    def findKthLargest(self, nums, k):
        f= self.helper(nums,0,len(nums)-1,k)
        print(f)
```

I've even printed (arr[p]) INSIDE the helper method and it gave me the correct answer however inside of the method findKthLargest the variable f shows up as a none type and I was wondering where did I go wrong? At the moment I believe that it is returning a none type since inside of the recursive loops when checking if (left>=right) inside of the helper method it returns none

Comment: The `helper()` function has three return points, only one of which returns a value.  The other two will return none.

Comment: @JohnGordon I see, hm what would you say should fix this issue?

Comment: I assume the fix would be something along the lines of "Rewrite the function so it cannot return none".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `helper` function does not always return a value. Only in the base case, where the `if` condition is true, it will return a numeric value. But it should also return that same number where the corresponding recursive calls are made.

So change:

```
self.helper(arr,left,p-1,k)
self.helper(arr,p+1,right,k)
```

to:

```
result = self.helper(arr,left,p-1,k)
if result is not None:
    return result
return self.helper(arr,p+1,right,k)
```

This way the deepest return value will bubble up the recursion tree, and a success in the first recursive call will avoid that the second recursive call is made.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to debug your code, this'd pass though with less statements:

```
class Solution:
    def findKthLargest(self, nums, k):
        def kth_smallest(nums, k):
            if nums:
                pos = partition(nums, 0, len(nums) - 1)
                if k > pos + 1:
                    return kth_smallest(nums[pos + 1:], k - pos - 1)
                elif k < pos + 1:
                    return kth_smallest(nums[:pos], k)
                else:
                    return nums[pos]

        def partition(nums, left, right):
            res = left
            while left < right:
                if nums[left] < nums[right]:
                    nums[left], nums[res] = nums[res], nums[left]
                    res += 1
                left += 1
            nums[res], nums[right] = nums[right],  nums[res]
            return res

        return kth_smallest(nums, len(nums) + 1 - k)
```